# How to fetch data remotely for displaying into admin/index.html in django adminlte v3

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin, adminlte

In Django AdminLte3, I want to show custom dashboard along with others Admin models. The data of the dashboard will come from remote server. And my custom dashboard will open by localhost:8000/admin/. How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

On your url define a new entry to a view:

**urls.py**

```
path('admin_dashboard/',admin_dashboard,name='admin_dashboard'),
```

**views.py**

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_dashboard(request):
    from django.contrib import admin

    context={} 
    #this makes the menu appear
    context['available_apps']=admin.site.get_app_list(request)
    
    return render(request,'admin/admin_dashboard.html',context)
```

On your settings (assuming you are using adminlte from jazzband):

```
JAZZMIN_SETTINGS = { 
     ...
     "topmenu_links": [
        # Url that gets reversed (Permissions can be added)
        {"name": "Home",  "url": "index",},
        {"name": "Dashboard",  "url": "admin_dashboard", }, 
    ],
    ...
```

This will make the link appear on top of the admin page, now its a regular view and a regular template and you can take it from there

Comment: Thanks @Walucas. I'm not using jazzband. How to add menu links in django adminlte3?

Comment: Let me check this library, I am not familiar.... jazzband is also adminlte3, so thats why I assumed it, my bad

Comment: @Papan you will have to extend the `_main_header.html` (https://github.com/d-demirci/django-adminlte3/blob/master/adminlte3/templates/adminlte/lib/_main_header.html) and put the url to the view there, and also have a template that extends the admin base.... take a look at jazzmin library, maybe its worth switching